# New to linux, trying to set up ubuntu on chromebook with crouton, but startlxde command is rendering errors

Tags: crash, chromebook, lxde

I downloaded crouton in developer mode using shell, and ran a command to set up lxde, but now when I type sudo startlxde is just comes up with error after a moment of black screen. I can post some of the console information but Im not sure how I should format it. If anyone has some advice it would be much appreciated.